# How could I compare strings in jquery match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am able to search and replace a string while finding the first word, can I match first 2 or 3 words or can I match the complete sentence including spacing

```
// Enlish text = "Name is not valid."
if ($(this).text().match("^Current")) {
    $(this).text('Nom est pas valable.');
}
```

Comment: Use regex delimiters and a literal notation: `.match(/^Current/)`.

Comment: Use `.match(/current/i)` for case-insensitive match.

Comment: Can you add some more information with example or cases.

Answer (score 1):

Should work, see basic example bellow :

```js
var example1 = "Current foo bar some extra test here";
var example2 = "foo Current bar";

if (example1.match("^Current foo bar")) 
    alert('1 ---- Nom est pas valable.');

if (example2.match("^Current")) 
    alert('2 ---- Nom est pas valable.');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, could I match "Current foo bar" complete sentence as I have many messages and they are starting with same first 2 or 3 words

Comment: Yes you can, just use `.match("^Current  foo bar")`.

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work do I have to add anything for spacing because in developer tool i can see the text "Name&nbsp;is&nbsp;not&nbsp;valid."

Comment: I have these but doesn't work only  "if ($(this).text().match("^Name"))"   this is working with the first word search but I want to compare whole sentence

Comment: I'm using the whole sentence in my updated answer `if (example1.match("^Current foo bar"))`.

Answer (score 1):

^ is to match the beginning of the data.

```
var text = "Current in this world, Current in Current bar in it for example Current in Current for and again Current in world";
```

And if you want to check beginning of data then use

```
text.match(/^Current in this world/).
```

g is for global search. Meaning it'll match all occurrences.

```
if(matches = text.match(/Current in Current/g)) {
  console.log(matches);
}
```